# c# run process on non-admin right

Tags: c#

I started a process on admin rights:

```
psi.Verb = "runas";
process.StartInfo = psi;
process.Start();
```

But now this process have to start another application but on non admin rights.
Application works on non-admin rights.
How I can do this?

Comment: Just run 'another application' without 'psi.Verb = "runas"'...

Comment: Without psi.Verb second application is started with admin rights too.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [CreateProcessAsUser](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/advapi32/CreateProcessAsUser.html) from the WinAPI.

Try to use `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Token` to get the token to create the process with.